# Gradle Exec task running from command line build but not from Android build

Tags: android, python, unix, gradle, groovy

I am attempting to execute a python script from a Gradle task of type `Exec`. My main build task has a dependency on this task. Let's for this example call my build task `assembleProjectDebug`. Let's simplify the example also to this:

```
tasks.create(name: newFooTask, type: Exec) {
    commandLine "python", "doSomething.py"
}

tasks[assembleProjectDebug].dependsOn(newFooTask)
```

If I run `./gradlew assembleProjectDebug` from a terminal, my python script executes and all is well in the world. However if I attempt to build from Android Studio with `Build -> Make Project`, my python script will not execute.

I can confirm as well that my currently selected build variant is set to `projectDebug`, and can also confirm that when building from Android Studio, `:app:assembleProjectDebug` appears in the log leading me to believe that `assembleProjectDebug` task is or will be executed (I could be wrong there).

For the sake of brevity I have also left out where I assign an environment variable in my task which points my $PATH variable to the location of my python exec.

Is there any reason why, outside of me messing up the assignment of a proper $PATH variable for the subprocess, that a command line build will execute this task, yet a build from within Android Studio will not execute this task?

Comment: I can confirm that the dependent task `assembleProjectDebug` is being executed in both a terminal build and an Android Studio build, as I am seeing the output `:app:assembleProjectDebug` in both instances. In a terminal build, preceding `app:assembleProjectDebug`, the task it depends on `newFooTask` is being executed, however for an Android Studio build, `newFooTask` is not being executed, which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. Building from within Android Studio, my task dependency was not being executed as it was when building from the command line. This was due to having `Configure on Demand` selected in `Android Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler`. Android Studio applies this setting by default. You can read more about `Configure on Demand` here:

[Configure on Demand in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you'll need to set the [workingDir](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:workingDir) on the Exec task

Eg:

```
tasks.create(name: newFooTask, type: Exec) {
   commandLine "python", "doSomething.py"
   workingDir = projectDir
}
```